# How to remove the blank page from end of the word document

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am not able to remove the blank page from end of the word document. I tried the following ways but i couldn't. Can any one help me on this..

**First way :**

```
<div style="page-break-before:always;"/>
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!historyList.SIZE > 0}">
            <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!0}" /> 
            <div Style="font-size:20px; color: #000080"> <b>Version History</b> </div>
            <table style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:30%;text-align:left;font-size:15px">
                            Version #
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:30%;text-align:left;font-size:15px">
                            Created Date
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:30%;text-align:left;font-size:15px">
                            Reason For Change
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <apex:repeat var="history" value="{!historyList}">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:30%">
                                {!history.verNo}
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:30%">
                                {!history.createdDate}
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:30%">
                                {!history.reasonForChange}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

**Second Way:**

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!historyList.SIZE > 0}">
            <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!0}" /> 
            <div Style="font-size:20px; color: #000080"> <b>Version History</b> </div>
            <table style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:30%;text-align:left;font-size:15px">
                            Version #
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:30%;text-align:left;font-size:15px">
                            Created Date
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:30%;text-align:left;font-size:15px">
                            Reason For Change
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <apex:repeat var="history" value="{!historyList}">
                        <div style="{!if(cnt < 1, 'page-break-before:avoid;','page-break-before:always;')}">
                        <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:30%">
                                {!history.verNo}
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:30%">
                                {!history.createdDate}
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:30%">
                                {!history.reasonForChange}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </div>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Do you have header or footer in place? Try disabling them if you have it and if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Printing Word documents would be similar to printing PDFs in that you'll first want to add `contentType="application/msword"` to the `<Apex:page>` line in your code. Then, you'll want to use CSS that includes `@media` tags for print and for screen. I recommend you try something along the lines of the following:

```
@media print
{
   size: 8.5in 11in;/* width height */ 
   table { page-break-inside:auto }
   tr { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto;}
   thead { display:table-header-group }
}
```

See this [W3C reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#the-page) for more on the `@media tag` and paged media.

```
<#div style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
The stuff inside this div will move to a fresh page if it's too long to fit on the remainder of the current page.
<#/div>

@page { 
  size: 8.5in 11in;/* width height */ 
}
```

Add a new attribute to the page tag: `"ContentType"`:

- For Word: `contentType="application/msword"`